# Array of unknown bound usage in C programming

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, undefined-behavior

I output of below code is undefined when I ran multiple times. I would like to know why the output is undefined and what will be implication when I try to assign value to an array of unknown bound.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int a[]= {};
  int num_of_elements;
  int count = 0;

  printf("Enter the number of elements:\n");
  scanf("%d",&num_of_elements);

  printf("Enter the numbers:\n");
  for(count=0; count<num_of_elements; ++count)
  {
    scanf("%d", &a[count]);
  }
  printf("\n");

  for(count=0; count<num_of_elements; count++)
  {
    printf("%d,   ", a[count]);
  }
  printf("\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Output when run at different times:

```
Enter the number of elements:
2

Enter the numbers:
1 2

0,   0,
```

---

```
Enter the number of elements:
3

Enter the numbers:
1 2 3

0,   0,   2,
```

---

```
Enter the number of elements:
4

Enter the numbers:
1 2 3 4

0,   0,   2,   3,
Segmentation fault
```

---

```
Enter the number of elements:
5

Enter the numbers:
1 2 3 4 5

0,   0,   2,   3,   4,
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: `int a[]= {};` is no use - you must define the array *after* you know its size.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677157/can-size-of-array-be-determined-at-run-time-in-c

Comment: the posted code does not compile! It causes the compiler to output two messages:  1) `5:12: warning: ISO C forbids empty initializer braces [-Wpedantic]`  and 2) `5:7: error: zero or negative size array 'a'`  When compiling always enable the warnings.  Then fix those warnings.   (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` )

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to know why the output is undefined and what will be implication when I try to assign value to an array of unknown bound

The size of variable `a` will be `0`, as `num_of_elements` has not been `scanf`'ed at that point, so you can't store anything in it.

The solution is to declare the array ***after*** you have read its size from the user. This means :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num_of_elements;
    int count = 0;

    printf("Enter the number of elements:\n");
    scanf("%d", &num_of_elements);

    //define here your array
    int a[num_of_elements];

    ...

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Only if `__STDC_NO_VLA__` is *not* defined as a macro identifier.

Comment: @DeiDei the OP does not mention such a macro definition in his program... That's why I did not mention this.

Comment: Hi Marievi and others...Thanks for your inputs. Its clear now and thanks for introducing the C11 standards which gave me some insight

Comment: compiling this answer results in: 1) `12:5: error: variable sized objct may not be initialized.` 2) `12:30: warning: ISO C forbids empty initializer braces [-Wpedantic]`

Answer (score 1):

As a first hint, when you try to compile this with `gcc`using `-pedantic`, it will refuse to compile:

```
$ gcc -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -ocrap.exe crap.c
crap.c: In function 'main':
crap.c:5:12: warning: ISO C forbids empty initializer braces [-Wpedantic]
   int a[]= {};
            ^
crap.c:5:7: error: zero or negative size array 'a'
   int a[]= {};
       ^
```

And indeed, the size of such a variable is `0`, so you can't store *anything*  in it.

Still it is a valid syntax and has its uses, for example as a "flexible array member" of a structure:

```c
struct foo
{
    int bar;
    int baz[];
};

[...]

struct foo *myfoo = malloc(sizeof(struct foo) + 5 * sizeof(int));
// myfoo->baz can now hold 5 integers
```